# Callback function, responsible for updating state, passed as props to child component not triggering a state update

Tags: reactjs

The callback function (lies in Images component) is responsible for making a state update. I'm passing that function as props to the Modal component, and within it it's being passed into the ModalPanel component.

That function is used to set the state property, display, to false which will close the modal. Currently, that function is not working as intended.

Image Component:

```
class Images extends Component {
  state = {
    display: false,
    activeIndex: 0
  };

  handleModalDisplay = activeIndex => {
    this.setState(() => {
      return {
        activeIndex,
        display: true
      };
    });
  };

  closeModal = () => {
    this.setState(() => {
      return { display: false };
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { imageData, width } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        {imageData.resources.map((image, index) => (
          <a
            key={index}
            onClick={() => this.handleModalDisplay(index)}
          >
            <Modal
              closeModal={this.closeModal}
              display={this.state.display}
              activeIndex={this.state.activeIndex}
              selectedIndex={index}
            >
              <Image
                cloudName={CLOUDINARY.CLOUDNAME}
                publicId={image.public_id}
                width={width}
                crop={CLOUDINARY.CROP_TYPE}
              />
            </Modal>
          </a>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Images;
```

Modal Component:

```
const overlayStyle = {
  position: 'fixed',
  zIndex: '1',
  paddingTop: '100px',
  left: '0',
  top: '0',
  width: '100%',
  height: '100%',
  overflow: 'auto',
  backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.9)'
};

const button = {
  borderRadius: '5px',
  backgroundColor: '#FFF',
  zIndex: '10'
};

class ModalPanel extends Component {
  render() {
    const { display } = this.props;
    console.log(display)
    const overlay = (
      <div style={overlayStyle}>
        <button style={button} onClick={this.props.closeModal}>
          X
        </button>
      </div>
    );
    return <div>{display ? overlay : null}</div>;
  }
}

class Modal extends Component {
  render() {
    const {
      activeIndex,
      children,
      selectedIndex,
      display,
      closeModal
    } = this.props;
    let modalPanel = null;
    if (activeIndex === selectedIndex) {
      modalPanel = (
        <ModalPanel display={this.props.display} closeModal={this.props.closeModal} />
      );
    }

    return (
      <div>
        {modalPanel}
        {children}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Modal;
```

links to code
https://github.com/philmein23/chez_portfolio/blob/chez_portfolio/components/Images.js

https://github.com/philmein23/chez_portfolio/blob/chez_portfolio/components/Modal.js

Comment: rather giving the github link you could also added codes here. that will help users to save to go to the link to see the code

Comment: Thanks @AniruddhaDas - Just updated the post. Apologies for the laziness :)

Comment: now you can remove the links which divert user not to answer. let me edit this question if possible. see if looks good now

Comment: Looks good. Thanks again @AniruddhaDas

Comment: When you say "not triggering state update" do you mean the top level `closeModal` function isn't called?

Comment: *"Currently, that function is not working as intended"* What's happening? What have you done to debug the code? Have you verified whether the function is called at all?

Comment: The solution provided below worked as intended. But to answer above, @FelixKling I tried logging the function passed as props in the nested components and it was being called. I goofed up with my implementation as described below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're dealing with this modal through a very non-react and *hacky* way.

Essentially, in your approach, all the modals are *always* there, and when you click on image, **ALL** modals `display` state becomes true, and you match the index number to decide which content to show.
I suspect it's not working due to the multiple children of same key in Modal or Modal Panel.

I strongly suggest you to ditch current approach. Here's my suggestions:

1. Only a single `<Modal/>` in `Images` component.
2. Add `selectedImage` state to your `Images` component. Every time you click on an image, you set `selectedImage` to that clicked image object.
3. Pass `selectedImage` down to `Modal` to display the content you want.

This way, there is only **ONE** modal rendered at all time. The content changes dynamically depending on what image you click.

This is the working code I tweaked from your repo:

*(I'm not sure what to display as Modal content so I display `public_id` of image)*

**Images Component**

```
class Images extends Component {
  state = {
    display: false,
    selectedImage: null
  };

  handleModalDisplay = selectedImage => {
    this.setState({
      selectedImage,
      display: true
    })
  };

  closeModal = () => {
    //shorter way of writing setState
    this.setState({display: false})
  }

  render() {
    const { imageData, width } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        <Modal
          closeModal={this.closeModal}
          display={this.state.display}
          selectedImage={this.state.selectedImage}
        />
        {imageData.resources.map((image, index) => (
          <a
            //Only use index as key as last resort
            key={ image.public_id }
            onClick={() => this.handleModalDisplay(image)}
          >
            <Image
              cloudName={CLOUDINARY.CLOUDNAME}
              publicId={image.public_id}
              width={width}
              crop={CLOUDINARY.CROP_TYPE}
            />
          </a>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**Modal Component**

```
class Modal extends Component {
  render() {
    const { display, closeModal, selectedImage } = this.props;

    const overlayContent = () => {
      if (!selectedImage) return null; //for when no image is selected
      return (
        //Here you dynamically display the content of modal using selectedImage
        <h1 style={{color: 'white'}}>{selectedImage.public_id}</h1>
      )
    }

    const overlay = (
      <div style={overlayStyle}>
        <button style={button} onClick={this.props.closeModal}>
          X
        </button>
        {
          //Show Modal Content
          overlayContent()
        }
      </div>
    );
    return <div>{display ? overlay : null}</div>;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much man! Your solution helped and I appreciate the kind feedback for improvement. You are a badass man. @liren

Comment: glad that it helped :) nice portfolio you have there by the way!

Comment: :) Thank you for the compliment. Currently making this for a friend to help promote his artwork.